# Reading from a file, java using Scanner

Tags: java, try-catch, readfile

I have been trying out reading my file using Scanner.

The error i am getting is `NoSuchElementException: No line found`
All of the arrays are String arrays to store information from the file.
The delimiter being used is ";".

```
private void choice() {
        File file = new File("info.txt");

        try {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
            read.useDelimiter(";");
            while (read.hasNextLine()){
                if (read.hasNext()){
                    realName[i] = read.next();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                if (read.hasNext()){
                    userName[i] = read.next();                       
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                if (read.hasNext()){
                    password[i] = read.next();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                if (read.hasNext()){
                    address[i] = read.next();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                if (read.hasNext()){
                    contact[i] = read.next();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                if (read.hasNext()){
                    cardType[i] = read.next();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                if (read.hasNext()){
                    cardNo[i] = read.next();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
             }
        }
        catch ......
    }
```

If I use the code above, I will always be getting the `NoSuchElementException: No line found`.

Now I use the code below.. everything will be printed out nicely with no errors.

```
private void choice() {
        File file = new File("info.txt");

        try {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
            read.useDelimiter(";");
            while (read.hasNextLine()){
                realName = read.nextLine();
                System.out.println(realName);
            }
        }
        catch ......
    }
```

Everything will be printed nicely line by line. There will not be any problems but this is not what I wanted. I want to store them in arrays.

Is there anything that I have done wrong for the 1st part of the coding?

I also use `read.hasNext()` rather than `read.hasNextLine()`.
But there are also errors.

Any kind soul could help?

==Edit
Sorry. I did not show the datas in the info.txt, it goes like this.

```
Mr Dash;dash;dash123;Dash Lane 1;414924934;VISA;1219240241029021092
Mr Long;long;long123;Long Lane 1;3924929;MASTERCARD;123902039109329
```

Comment: Can you show contents of info.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `hasNextLine` once and `nextLine` more than once inside your loop so you might get error if it reaches `EOF`.
Since you are using delimiter I think you are trying to read each word from single line in a single iteration. Try this:

```
int i=0;
while (read.hasNextLine()){                
    realName[i] = read.next();
    userName[i] = read.next();
    password[i] = read.next();
    address[i] = read.next();
    contact[i] = read.next();
    cardType[i] = read.next();
    cardNo[i] = read.next();
    i++;               
}
```

Comment: Yeap. It is a single line with delimiter. There was an error when I use this code. Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException. The error was at cardType[i]. I presume this error happens when it cant get anything out from it?

Comment: Is it because at the last line there is no ";"? Hence it takes up both the 1st Card No and the next Real name and put them together into the variable?

Comment: I got them printed out and tested. It there anyway to ask the iterator to stop if there is nothing else to read? I think that its getting errors

Comment: Inside the while loop, if I just do a System.out.println(read.next()); . There is no errors and fine. When I do this array to store the information. The errors come out again.. Sigh

Comment: @John It will be better to help if you show us the contents of file.Edit your question and post few lines from your file so that we can see formatting of file and help you to find cause of error.

Answer (score 1):

Before every `read.nextLine()` you must check `read.hasNextLine()`, otherwise you might get exception!

May be somewhere in your `while` loop, you are doing `read.nextLine()` and there is no next line (EOF reached)

```
      while (read.hasNextLine()){
            for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
                    realName[i] = read.nextLine();
                    userName[i] = read.nextLine(); // check for read.hasNextLine();
                    password[i] = read.nextLine(); // check for read.hasNextLine();
                    address[i] = read.nextLine(); // check for read.hasNextLine();
                    contact[i] = read.nextLine(); // check for read.hasNextLine();
                    cardType[i] = read.nextLine(); // check for read.hasNextLine();
                    cardNo[i] = read.nextLine(); // check for read.hasNextLine();
           }
      }
```